# Authentication error cloning Azure Devop's repo in OS X

Tags: azure-devops

I have created a project in my Azure DevOps but when I try to clone it with Visual Studio Code or SourceTree it asks me for the password and the password I use is the one associated with my account, which is the Azure tenant administrator account with which I have logged into Azure DevOps and with which I have created the project.

but he always rejects me

[image: sourcetree]

[image: VS Code]

I have the latest git version installed in OSX

[image: git version]

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be related to the Git credential in your local, try to remove them and try again.

If it still does not work, you could use [PAT(personal access token)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) to clone the repo, it should work.

```
git clone https://<Your-PAT-Here>@dev.azure.com/orgname/proname/_git/reponame
```